# Getting the user in a 1-to-n relationship where the condition is on the n-table

Tags: mysql

I hope the title is not too confusing.I have the following 1-to-n relationship.

users

```
+---------------+------------------+
| Field         | Type             |
+---------------+------------------+
| id            | int(11) unsigned |
| title_id      | int(11) unsigned |
| firstname     | varchar(255)     |
| lastname      | varchar(255)     |
+---------------+------------------+
```

user_courses

```
+------------+------------------+
| Field      | Type             |
+------------+------------------+
| id         | int(11) unsigned |
| user_id    | int(11)          |
| course_id  | int(11)          |
+------------+------------------+
```

A user can have multiple courses. Let's assume I want to get all users where the user has course 1 AND 2 AND 3. Is this possible in one query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is. You need to `JOIN` users table ON `user_id`, then you can add any column from `user_courses` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: do you want to find only those users which has only course_id 1, 2 and 3 OR you want to find all those users which has atleast selected course_id 1,2 and 3

Comment: I want to find the users who have, in this case, this 3 courses.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use `JOIN` with `WHERE` to get all the users with their courses. Then, use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) with `GROUP BY` to get all the courses of a user in *comma-separated values*.

Eventually, utilize [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function, to check that the comma-separated courses have 1, 2 **and** 3 in them.

**Case 1:** If you want to find all those users, which has atleast selected course_id 1, 2 and 3, then utilize `FIND_IN_SET` as below:

```
SELECT u.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uc.course_id) AS courses 
FROM users AS u 
JOIN user_courses AS uc ON uc.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('1', courses) > 0 
  AND FIND_IN_SET('2', courses) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('3', courses) > 0
```

**Case 2:** If you want to find all those users, which has selected course_id 1, 2 and 3 only, then use the following:

```
SELECT u.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uc.course_id ORDER BY uc.course_id ASC) AS courses 
FROM users AS u 
JOIN user_courses AS uc ON uc.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING courses = '1,2,3'
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out tomorrow and give feedback if this works!

Comment: @ChristianTimm no worries. If it works for you, do consider upvoting and accepting the answer :)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: A Question: Is the 'WHERE' necessary?

Comment: @ChristianTimm check edited answer now :) Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `WHERE IN` clause to fetch all the users following a list of courses.

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
JOIN user_courses
    ON user_courses.user_id = users.id
WHERE user_courses.course_id IN (1, 2, 3)             --At this point we have the list of users following courses 1, 2 OR 3
GROUP BY users.id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_courses.course_id) = 3 --To filter the result for the users following 3 courses from the 1, 2, 3 selected above
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/922fb9b/8)

Comment: Works too. Thank you!

Comment: I upvoted your solution. It doesn't show in public because i am below 15 points.